# How to prove if this is false or not?

Tags: geometry, tiling

Can you cover the planar with regular pentagons and decagons(all of their sides are 1 unit long), without any holes or overlaps?

I think that the answer is no, but can't really prove it.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do the polygons have any other restrictions? Do they need to be regular, or convex, and do we need to use both? I can tile the plane using two kinds of pentagons with unit sides, one not convex.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that, they need to be regular, and the task mentions that you can use both, but not neccessarily need to use them, if you can do it with one of them only, that works too.

Answer (score 2):

Think about what has to happen at the vertices of the tiling, comparing to Platonic or Archimedean tilings. Four squares meeting at a vertex works because it just so happens that $4\cdot 90^\circ = 360^\circ$. Two octagons and a square works because $2\cdot 135^\circ + 90^\circ = 360^\circ$.

What are the possible sums of angles meeting at a vertex if you're only allowed to use pentagons and decagons?

This won't be the complete end of the story, but it gives you a starting point for what configurations are allowable at each vertex, and you'll be able to see what those configurations imply.